# javascript iterating array of objects using checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, checkbox

I want to show `div` when `checkbox`is true and hide `div` when `checkbox` is false. For this reason I have created an array of objects, which have property(checkboxes and divs) and value(selectors of checkboxes and divs). But this code doesn't work. Where have I done a mistake?

https://jsfiddle.net/9LzLm9hx/9/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just change  .attr("checked")  to .is(":checked")

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand why you give this useless piece of code:

```
<label for="common"></label> <span>Common</span>
```

Can be made useful this way:

```
<label for="common"> <span>Common</span></label>
```

And to solve your issue, rename the `id` of the checkboxes to match the class of the `div`s:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="post-id" />
<input type="checkbox" id="post-activation" />
```

And the `<div>`s:

```
<div class='col-xs-3 post-id'>id</div>
<div class='col-xs-3 post-activation'>active</div>
```

Then using jQuery:

```
$(function () {
    $("input:checkbox").change(function () {
        if (this.checked)
            $("." + this.id).show();
        else
            $("." + this.id).hide();
    });
});
```